# awesome wm / Save application window size and location on different tags

Tags: awesome-wm

Is it possible to save application window size and location on different tags, e.g. I want to have text editor on tag 1, browser on tag 2, and half-screen editor + half-screen browser on tag 3?

There should be one instance of the browser and one instance of the text editor in this case. I think I can work-around it having multiple instances of applications, but still curious if it is possible, one suggestion is to have the application resized when switching tags.